# Auto move specific file type from one folder to another

Tags: windows, batch-file

I know i can use the below code to move all files from a source folder to a destination folder but how would i do this with a specific file type, for example, move all .mp3 files from source folder to destination folder and leave everything else behind (jpg, mp4 etc).

```
echo off
set X=<days>
set "source=C:\<Source Folder Path>"
set "destination=D:\<Destination Folder Path>"
robocopy "%source%" "%destination%" /mov /minage:%X%
exit /b
```

Comment: See `for /?` this is not related to WSL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you open a Command Prompt window, type either `help robocopy` or `robocopy /?`, and press the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key, you should see that the correct syntax is provided at the outset:

```batch-file
ROBOCOPY source destination [file [file]...] [options]
```

What you need to do is utilise the `[file [file]...]` part of the command.

```batch-file
ROBOCOPY "%source%" "%destination%" "*.mp3" /Mov /MinAge:%X%
```

Putting it together as a batch file, it may look like this:

```batch-file
@Echo Off
Set "X=<Number of days>"
Set "source=C:\<Source directory path>"
Set "destination=D:\<Destination directory path>"
%__AppDir__%Robocopy.exe "%source%" "%destination%" "*.mp3" /Mov /MinAge:%X%
Exit /B
```

*Please make sure that neither the source or destination paths are terminated with  path separators, **`\`**, as those will escape your doublequotes and essentially break the command.*